# MySQL: update table records by sum from another table

Tags: mysql

I need to sum all time from "user_answers.time" and update "question.total_time", for all records

note: (user_answers.qid foreign key refer to question.id)

tables structure:

"question" table:

```
id     total_time
1          0
2          0
3          0
4          0
5          0
```

"user_answers" table:

```
id     qid     time
1       1       3
2       1       44
3       2       3.2
4       3       2
5       1       5
6       4       1
```

I need to finish with "question" table like this:

```
id     total_time
1          52
2          3.2
3          2
4          1
5          0
```

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE question
SET total_time = (SELECT SUM(time) FROM user_answers WHERE question.id = user_answers.qid)
```